# tag for community involvement?

Tags: support, feature-request

In [FAQ](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq) the questions about community involvement are allowed but there is not tag for it. Would it be a good idea to have one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tag is [community-drupal-org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-drupal-org).

> This tag is for questions about Drupal.org, and its community.

I kept the tag description a little vague, but it is the tag that should be used for questions about Drupal.org as community, how to get involved on Drupal.org, and what one should do when involved in Drupal.org initiatives.

As for the other questions, bug reports should be reported in the right issue queue.

As examples of questions using [community-drupal-org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-drupal-org), I can think of the following. (They are the first examples to which I can think of; I cannot guarantee I thought to perfectly acceptable questions. `;)`)

- I saw a bug in a module, and I would like to contribute back to that module. How should I do?
- What is the steps to follow to become maintainer/co-maintainer of a module that apparently stopped to be developed?