# Is it appropriate to ask about DrupalCon in the context of Community involvement?

Tags: discussion, support

The question "[What is the company that will organize DrupalCon Europe 2019?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269461/what-is-the-company-that-will-organize-drupalcon-europe-2019)" was voted down and then put on hold.

Upon revisiting the existing guidelines, it seems that the question is valid. These are the findings:

#### 1/ The stated reason doesn't not apply

The statement:

> "Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, module, theme, distribution, tutorial, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

The question is not asking for a recommendation. Then, there were attempts to find the answer searching on google and on the drupal.org site, but it is not mentioned, because it is implicit, it is expected that you try to find the answer as part of the due diligence.

One could argue that the question is off-topic, but there are reasons to think otherwise which are explained next.

#### 2/ On the *[What topics can I ask about here?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)* page, it reads:

> If your question is about one of the following topics, you're in the right place to ask your question!
>
> - ...
> - Community involvement

#### 3/ On the *[Ask a question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)* form, it says:

> If your question is about code, include the relevant parts.

So, the question can be about something else other than code.

#### 4/ Precedent of existing content and voted questions

- [The tag community-official-site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/community-official-site)
- [Q: Where can I find the upcoming DrupalCamps and DrupalCon?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128564/where-can-i-find-the-upcoming-drupalcamps-and-drupalcon)
- [Q: How to access past DrupalCon website that requires password?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2442/how-to-access-past-drupalcon-website-that-requires-password)
- [Q: How can I watch videos of the presentations from DrupalCon Sydney for free?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64074/how-can-i-watch-videos-of-the-presentations-from-drupalcon-sydney-for-free)

Comment: The closing reason also include questions asking to find an off-site resource. Since an useful answer should give a link to prove the answer is correct, I take the closing reason  suits the question.

Comment: Also, notice that the last question you listed has been closed in 2013 as off-topic, 4 hours after it was asked. It cannot be used as prove that your question should not be closed, since that question is... closed.

Comment: The **off-site resource** in the on-hold statement refers to asking for a **off-site resource recommendation**, not just to off-site resources in general. 
It would be wrong to ask "**what is _a company_ which could successfully organize a DrupalCon?**".
But the question is about _the company_ that got the licensing.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I am glad you joined the discussion. 
I was just thinking about linking this question, because you say 
"I kept the tag description [of the community-official-site tag] a little vague, but it is the tag that should be used
 for questions about Drupal.org as community, how to get involved ...", 
 so I thought I was preaching your gospel here
https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2309/tag-for-community-involvement

Comment: Is there a bug in my logic? 
#1 DrupalCon is about the community, 
#2 it is a fact that Kuoni will organize the next DrupalCon Europe and possibly others.
Does it not follow that you need to know who is Kouni in order to be involved in the community in certain parts of the world?
It would be easier to grasp the whole thing if the Drupal Associatiation would handle everything as before, but that is not case anymore. This is new ground, but it is what it is.

Comment: Even if there are questions about a topic that are on-topic, not all the questions on that topic are acceptable/on-topic. A question about which organization will organize an event is one of those questions.